# Google Tag Manager + NuxtJs creates duplicate scripts

Tags: nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

I have installed the GTM module for NuxtJs (https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module)

I use the "nuxtRoute" as trigger in GTM and it is working fine.

**Problem**: Since it is a "Single page application" the tracking scripts will pile up because the HTML is not re-rendered for each page view.
So lets say I'm inserting a "Hotjar Tracking Code" on each page view, the Hotjar script will be inserted 20 times into the HTML dom if the user navigates to 20 pages.

Is this a problem? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a problem.

But it's very easy to avoid. Fire your library initialization tags on the actual pageload rather than nuxtRoutes.

Only fire pageviews on nuxtRoutes. Hotjar has to have a manual for SPA implementation. Here: https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011805428-Hotjar-on-Single-Page-Apps

It looks like hotjar is smart enough to listen to history changes on it's own, not requiring GTM's help to know when a navigation happens. So only deploy their code once per real pageview and you should be good.

It is unlikely, but it's possible that hotjar would have issues with page tracking. That case is actually described in their article. In that case, you would have to use your route trigger.